# Size of YouTube Subscribe Circle and Video Rectangle

Tags: measurement

I need to design a custom **YouTube End Screen**.

My intention is to place the *Subscribe element* inside a *circle* and *Video element* inside a *rectangle*. What's the default size of **Subscribe Circle** and **Video Rectangle**?

End Screen sample is shown below. I asked this question earlier in [Video StackExchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/), and users recommended to post it here.

[image: Size of YouTube Subscribe Circle and Video Rectangle]

Comment: There is no standard for YouTube end screens as far as I know. Different channels use different sizes and different elements.

Comment: My mistake. I meant default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? She has a size template you can download: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/tutorial-youtubes-new-end-screens-tara-hunt

Comment: That's it! That's what I'm looking for! Thank you @Harley

Answer (score 0):

if you want the exact dimension for End Screen elements. You will find it here... https://youtu.be/FSXHQRshsA4

Comment: If you can please post the dimensions in your answer in the event that the video is taken down.